# Translating data-bound text in Angular 2 with i18n

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, internationalization

When I attempt to translate English to French using i18n everything works dandy when following the Internationalization tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html word for word.

**But** the moment I attempt to use Angular 2's data-binding to insert variable text into the HTML it quits working.

Here is my HTML:

`<h1 i18n="User welcome|An introduction header for this sample">{{value}}</h1>`

Here is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  public value = "Hello i18n!";
}
```

Here is my XLF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
 <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
   <body>
     <trans-unit id="af2ccf4b5dba59616e92cf1531505af02da8f6d2"   datatype="html">
       <source>Hello i18n!</source>
       <target>Bonjour i18n!</target>
       <note priority="1" from="description">An introduction header for this sample</note>
       <note priority="1" from="meaning">User welcome</note>
     </trans-unit>
   </body>
 </file>
</xliff>
```

Here is the error:

> zone.js@0.6.25:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse
>   errors:
>       Translation unavailable for message id="95184d0fe43359bff724d20df3a1317aef86799c" 
>       ("[ERROR ->]{{value}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot currently translate strings at run-time. It's pre-processed to deliver the translated strings in the html. It would be nice if Angular would provide a pipe to use the .xlf translations for bound string variables. Seems like a pretty big gap to me.

Here's a [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjvbNpCnVDRjrHwIjTZc?p=preview) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I beat my head on this for a while, with no success. In the end I went with [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) rather then the recommended way. It works like a charm, because it uses pipes to trigger the translation as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is functional example of that what you are trying to achieve: [plnkr link](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-i18n/ts/plnkr.html)

Looks like you have to set up document locale, and a little bit extra code for fetching the proper localisation in `app/i18n-providers.ts`

Comment: @Dralac: Thank you for fixing the link, but that does not resolve the issue. The issue is with bound data,  the "{{value}}" in the Html file is messing up the translator.

Comment: There is new ng2 release since yesterday where they fixed few bugs related with i18n. You can give it a shoot. [see changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)